# In CakePHP 3.X using addCase how should I define a value as a fallback?

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.x

Given the following relation:

- Centers belongsTo Cities

I've created a finder in Centers to return the names of the centers with the city code (if that city code exists).

I've successfully created my query using `if` as below:

```
public function findWithCityCode(Query $query, array $options = [])
{
    $expression = $query->func()->if([
        $query->func()->length(['Cities.code' => 'identifier']),
        $query->func()->concat([
            '(',
            'Cities.code' => 'identifier',
            ')',
            ' ',
            'Centers.name' => 'identifier'
        ]),
        'Centers.name' => 'identifier'
    ]);
    return $query->contain(['Cities'])->select(['name' => $expression]);
}
```

But that does not work for sqlite, as sqlite does not have the `IF` function. That's why I'm converting my query to use `CASE` instead of `IF`, but here comes the problem:

```
public function findWithCityCode(Query $query, array $options = [])
{
    $expression = $query->newExpr()->addCase([
        $query->func()->length(['Cities.code' => 'identifier']),
    ],[
        $query->func()->concat([
            '(',
            'Cities.code' => 'identifier',
            ')',
            ' ',
            'Centers.name' => 'identifier'
        ]),
        'Centers.name' // here's the problem
    ],['string']);
    return $query->contain(['Cities'])->select(['name' => $expression]);
}
```

Doing it this way works for the `IF`, but it shows `Centers.name` for the `ELSE` instead of the real `Centers.name` value:

```
[
    (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Center) {
        'name' => '(MAD) PALACIO SANTA ANA',
    [...]
  }
]
```

But for the `else`, the results show `Centers.name` instead of the real `Centers.name` value:

```
[
    (int) 15 => object(App\Model\Entity\Center) {
        'name' => 'Centers.name',
    [...]
]
```

I've tried changing `Centers.name` with `['Centers.name' => 'identifier']` and similar convinations but none of them work.

Can anyone help me with this?

**Edit: After finding the duplicate thanks to @ndm I add here the solution for easy access (that way you don't need to traverse among links and read new questions). The solution was to use `Cake\Database\Expression\IdentifierExpression`:**

```
public function findWithCityCode(Query $query, array $options = [])
{
    $expression = $query->newExpr()->addCase([
        $query->func()->length(['Cities.code' => 'identifier']),
    ],[
        $query->func()->concat([
            '(',
            'Cities.code' => 'identifier',
            ')',
            ' ',
            'Centers.name' => 'identifier'
        ]),
        new Cake\Database\Expression\IdentifierExpression('Centers.name') // here's the solution
    ],['string']);
    return $query->contain(['Cities'])->select(['name' => $expression]);
}
```

Comment: I believe you're asking the same as **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33383845/what-type-do-i-specify-in-addcase-to-return-a-column**?

Comment: yeah, it seems so, I'll give it a try. Thanks @ndm